# How can I handle encoding properly when passing data from a news feed to an IRC server

Tags: python, irc, bots

Code:

```
import socket, feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse("http://pwnmyi.com/feed")
latest = feed.entries[0]
art_name = latest.title

network = 'irc.rizon.net'
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((network, port))
print irc.recv(4096)
irc.send('NICK PwnBot\r\n')
irc.send('USER PwnBot PwnBot PwnBot :PwnBot by Fike\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN #pwnmyi\r\n')
while True:
    data = irc.recv(4096)
    if data.find('PING') != -1:
        irc.send('PONG ' + data.split() [1] + '\r\n')
    if data.find( '!latest' ) != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG #pwnmyi :Latest Article: ' + art_name + '\r\n')
```

It connects etc., but then when I do !latest in the channel, it just quits with this:

```
    irc.send('PRIVMSG #pwnmyi :Latest Article: ' + art_name + '\r\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Could you please help me debug this code? It used to work for me before.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: "something about a unicode error"?  What are we supposed to do?  Guess what something about a unicode error might mean?  Or could you provide some hint or clue?

Comment: @Jochen that didn't help one bit.

Comment: Im guessing this would be a great use of idk, twisted.

Comment: @Fike: "Status" comments like "edited." don't help much and don't mean anything to other folks with the similar question.  Further, StackOverflow has a delightfully complete change log, so it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the IRC protocol does not define a particular character set encoding used for messages, rather it's an 8bit protocol, which has certain octets used for control characters.  (See [rfc1459 section 2.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt).

[Apparently](http://blog.nix.is/irc-and-character-encoding) the popular mIRC client will decode utf8 sequences if it recognizes them as such, and this makes pretty decent sense for irc's use since ascii codepoints are encoded with the same bytes as the ascii characters, and non-ascii codepoints are all encoded as values > 127.

In python, that's spelled `unicode.encode(encoding='utf8')` like so:

```
>>> u'\u0ca0_\u0ca0'.encode('utf8')
'\xe0\xb2\xa0_\xe0\xb2\xa0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to encode the string you post to the IRC server. Also, depending on what feedparser returns, you might want to decode it from a specific encoding.

Encoding depends on what does the feed contain.

Comment: feedparser returns a unicode string (or whatever). If I test it in the interpreter, it comes up as u'Blah sojbhsoub'.

Comment: Well - that "or whatever" part is your problem. You can't ignore the encoding and you need to know exactly what you receive. Is it `str`? `bytes`? `unicode`? which version of python? if it's 2.x and it's an `str` is it decoded or encoded? Read http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html to learn about it. If it's "or whatever" then your code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

`latest.title` has non-ASCII characters in it.

You must either remove them, escape them or translate them.

The cheap and easy way out is to use `repr()`

```
    irc.send('PRIVMSG #pwnmyi :Latest Article: ' + repr(art_name) + '\r\n')
```

Or better

```
    irc.send('PRIVMSG #pwnmyi :Latest Article: {0!r}\r\n'.format( art_name ) )
```

In the long run, you need to address non-ASCII characters in your input.

Comment: Using `repr` gives me "Latest Article: u'Apple Releases iOS 4.3.4 To Patch JailbreakMe PDF Exploit'" in the channel, which isn't what I want. Your second example is Python 3, I'm using 2.7.

Comment: @Fike: `format` is part of Python 2.7.  While the unpleasant `u"` is unpleasant, at least it works.  Now you have to find a better way to translate the Unicode character in that string to ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd recommend converting all strings to 'utf-8', you can encode/decode unicode strings using this:

```
def decode(bytes):
    try:
        text = bytes.decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        try:
            text = bytes.decode('iso-8859-1')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            text = bytes.decode('cp1252')
    return text


def encode(bytes):
    try:
        text = bytes.encode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        try:
            text = bytes.encode('iso-8859-1')
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            text = bytes.encode('cp1252')
    return text
```

This is an excellent website that explains Python's Unicode: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode

The best 3 tips from it are:

1. Decode early
2. Unicode everywhere
3. Encode late